# glGetUniformLocation and glUseProgram give the error invalid operation (1282). Can anyone help resolve the issue?

Tags: java, opengl, shader

Right now I am building a 3d game engine to make it easier to program 3d games. Everything has been working well up until I got a new computer. On the old one which was a windows vista PC it worked fine, now I am using a windows 8 PC and the methods that are used to get the uniform locations for my shaders are giving the error invalid operation (1282).

```
org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid operation (1282)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Util.checkGLError(Util.java:59)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glGetUniformLocation(GL20.java:664)
    at lib.ogl.graphicEffects.shaders.shaderProgram.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram.java:50)
    at lib.ogl.graphicEffects.shaders.StaticShader.getAllUniformLocations(StaticShader.java:45)
    at lib.ogl.graphicEffects.shaders.shaderProgram.<init>(shaderProgram.java:44)
    at lib.ogl.graphicEffects.shaders.StaticShader.<init>(StaticShader.java:32)
    at lib.org.Engine.engine.run(engine.java:72)
    at lib.org.Game.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:37)
```

I think that it is a problem with linking the shader but I do not know how to test that or how to fix it.

the code looks like this:

```
public shaderProgram(String vertexFile, String fragmentFile){
        vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        programID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        bindAttributes();
        glLinkProgram(programID);
if(glGetProgrami(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS)==GL_FALSE){
    Debug.Errorlog("failure in linking the shader program");
    System.exit(-1);
}
glValidateProgram(programID);
if(glGetProgrami(programID, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS)==GL_FALSE){
    Debug.Errorlog("failure in validating the shader program");
    System.exit(-1);
}
        getAllUniformLocations();
    }
```

The loadShader class correctly loads the shader.
The problem occurs when the program attempts to link the shaders I will add in the code for loading the shaders, but it does not appear to be the problem:

```
*public static int loadShader(String file, int type){
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Debug.log("could not load the shader file : " + file);
        }
        int shaderID = glCreateShader(type);
        glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
        glCompileShader(shaderID);
        if(glGetShaderi(shaderID,GL_COMPILE_STATUS)==GL_FALSE){
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID,500);//TODO DEBUG.log?
            Debug.Errorlog("Could not compile the shader");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return shaderID;
    }
```

The getAllUniformLocations methods looks like this:

```
protected void getAllUniformLocations() {
    try{
        location_transformationMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
        location_projectionMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
        location_viewMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("viewMatrix");
        location_shineDamper = super.getUniformLocation("shineDamper");
        location_reflectivity = super.getUniformLocation("reflectivity");
        location_skyColor = super.getUniformLocation("skyColor");

        location_lightPosition = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];
        location_lightcolor = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];
        location_attenuation = new int [MAX_LIGHTS];
        for(int x = 0; x < MAX_LIGHTS; x ++){
            location_lightPosition[x] = super.getUniformLocation("lightPosition["+x+"]");
            location_lightcolor[x] = super.getUniformLocation("lightColor["+x+"]");
            location_attenuation[x] = super.getUniformLocation("attenuation["+x+"]");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Every time it attempts to load the first uniform, it catches the error and prints the stacktrace that I presented above.

Could it be a problem that my old graphics card overlooked?

It turns out the real problem is that after compiling correctly, the shaders fail to link to the program!

Comment: I see no evidence of any code *verifying* that the shader loaded has correctly compiled/linked.

Comment: Use `glGetError` at the very least to trace *where* the error occurs. Also - do you have an OpenGL context/window at this point?

Comment: To respond to Nicol, how would you go about checking that, I looked it up but it seems that you need other libraries besides OpenGL. How would you do it only with OpenGL?

Comment: To respond to Brett, I know that the error is being caused when you try to get the uniform locations, it is most likely because of a link failure but I would not know how to fix that.

Comment: @gozaimo http://docs.gl/gl4/glGetShader

Comment: Looking over my code, i just realized that i had not imported opengl 45 when i thought i got them all. That is the reason why i could not use that function. That helps open many opertunities to fix it. Thanks for the help @PeterT

Comment: @gozaimo glGetShaderiv has been there since OpenGL 2.0. The only reason I can imagine you'd have a lower version is either no hardware support or too simplified wgl loading

Comment: @PeterT. I checked the hardware and the computer supports opengl 4.5. What is even weider is that my old computer does not suppoet 4.5 but it does have the glGetShaderiv function. I can look into the wgl loading though.

Comment: @gozaimo oh, I didn't see that it was actually Java that you are using, most Java OpenGL loaders like to be very specific about which version functions were added in. In lwjgl it's "GL20.glGetShaderi" (they also omit the 'v' at the end because those are usually the pointer functions)

Comment: @PeterT thank you so much, I used the function and confirmed that it was a problem LINKING the shader program. It was NOT a problem COMPILING them. I will put the new code in question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, The problem was just my stupidity!
I printed the info log after catching that the shaders did not link correctly and found out that some of the variables in one shader did not match the ones in the other shader!

```
The fragment shader uses varying toCameraVector, but previous shader does not write to it.
Type mismatch: Type of toLightVector different between shaders.
```

Sorry to waste everyone's time, but you did help me figure out what the problem was and for that, I thank you I can finally resolve this issue.